# What key positions in 1969 USA would aliens need to influence to control the US nuclear arsenal?

Tags: alternate-history, cold-war, conspiracy

It is 1969, the conspiracy theorists are all correct and aliens are secretly trying to control everything. But

- the Reptoids are refugees
- very limited in number
- concerned about being exposed

Other hostile aliens vie for control of humanity and the reptoids want to assure control of the US. Key to this is guaranteeing control of US nuclear forces (both to attack enemies and prevent WWIII, as needed).

If you are a group of mind-controlling reptoids in 1969 who can imitate humans, which key positions in the US government/military must you control to guarantee you control the US nuclear arsenal, to launch (missiles), send (bombers), or withhold attack?

- Limit the scope to control of nuclear forces.
- Reptoids can only copy/influence a relatively small number of targets (ideally 5 or less). the More people copied/controlled, the higher the risk of exposure.

Comment: Why is the nuclear arsenal so specifically important, since the reptilian conspiracy theorist are correct, why not take from their playbook and mind control/impersonate top bankers and defense business owners, then fund a secret internal projects to control the nuclear arsenal along with everything else?

Comment: For how long do you need to exert control once you start doing your non-normal operations?

Comment: Nuclear arsenal is key because the Reptoids fear additional aliens arriving that would require counterattack (1st priority: keep Earth out of enemy hands) on Earth but also having their resource base destroyed by war (2nd priority: Earth as resource). There are more reptoids controlling industry, other countries, etc. but I'm keeping my focus limited because the strategic forces are critical to story and plot development. Plus not all other reptoids are cooperative or socially responsible enough to care.

Comment: In this case, we would assume the goal would be to either start an attack to kill "invading" Aliens, or stop an attack long enough for cooler heads to intervene. If their subjects all disappeared/committed suicide afterwards to avoid detection, they wouldn't care.

Comment: What is the our purpose of controlling US nuclear arsenal? Are we also evil aliens trying to control humans or we are just trying to make sure we have our own proxy on this planet so when other evil aliens are trying to kill us through their Earthly proxy, we have our own Earthly proxy to fight back? And why do we need to use mind-control rather than propaganda or money-control?

Comment: @FaitoDayo The Reptoids are of limited means and numbers, so they control as much as they can, but they are still a tiny number of aliens on Earth. Money and propaganda won't allow a rapid nuclear response to a sudden unexpected appearance of rival aliens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go for the POTUS (President Of The United States), as that's the only figure who can order a nuclear attack, having the famous nuclear briefcase at hand.

I think during the Vietnam war, aptly happening in the years you are referring to, a US army high rank was trying to get nukes for cleaning up the war theater and was put apart for this, while [even](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vietnam_War#Nuclear_threats_and_diplomacy)

> On 27 October 1969, Nixon had ordered a squadron of 18 B-52s loaded with nuclear weapons to race to the border of Soviet airspace to convince the Soviet Union, in accord with the madman theory, that he was capable of anything to end the Vietnam War.

Comment: My only concern with the president is that because he's so publicly visible, risk of exposure is high (and the first place enemies would go to is DC to control the president). The Reptoids in the USSR have their own agenda & politics, and are a separate issue. I figured Nixon would be on the list, though.

Answer (score 1):

Some commanders of nuclear bombers in South Korea would probably be enough. Unknown to most the ability to launch nuclear attacks was widely delegated down the command chain to survive a decapitation attack on Washington.

> As an example of the third concern, [Ellsberg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daniel_Ellsberg#The_Doomsday_Machine) discussed an interview he
>   had in 1958 with a major, who commanded a squadron of 12 F-100
>   fighter-bombers at Kunsan Air Base, South Korea. His aircraft were
>   equipped with Mark 28 thermonuclear weapons with a yield of 1.1
>   megatons each, roughly half the explosive power of all the bombs
>   dropped by the US in World War II both in Europe and the Pacific. The
>   major said his official orders were to wait for orders from his
>   superiors in Osan Air Base, South Korea, or in Japan before ordering
>   his F-100s into the air. However, the major also said that standard
>   military doctrine required him to protect his forces. That meant that
>   if he had reason to believe that a war had already begun when his
>   communications with Osan and Japan were broken, he was required to
>   launch his dozen F-100s with their thermonuclear weapons. They never
>   practiced that launch, because the risk of an accident was too great.
>   Ellsberg then asked what might happen if he gave such launch orders
>   and the sixth plane succumbed to a thermonuclear accident on the
>   runway. After some thought, the major agreed that the five planes
>   already in the air would likely conclude that a nuclear war had begun,
>   and they would likely deliver their warheads to their preassigned
>   targets.

And it was possible (even easy) for a pilot to fake the attack order. Ellsberg makes for some truly eye opening reading.

Combine that with a SIOP that only knew all-out attack and you can easily go to nuclear winter.

Further reading: [Command and Control: Nuclear Weapons, the Damascus Accident, and the Illusion of Safety](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_and_Control_(book)) by Eric Schlosser.

Comment: Part of the Reptoid agenda is preventing nuclear war if it is likely to happen (assume getting past this stage of social evolution is a bottleneck for civilizations). Does this mean there are hundreds of reptoids required to secure the arsenal?  We may need to alter history to get tighter C&C so fewer Reptoids can control the arsenal.

Comment: @DWKraus Try to control the Soviets, they probably had tighter C&C.

Comment: Yes, I agree. The factional nature of the reptoids unfortunately means the Soviets were the enemies of the US, but also the soviet reptoids don't entirely trust the US reptoids and vice versa. Both sides are maintaining a political house of cards trying to control the humans while fearing outside enemies and barely tolerating each other. The question structure says to keep from bringing in too much story to the question, thus the narrow focus.